# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Tags: java, https, server

This code is working in my laptop having latest java version. but not working in pc with java 1.5. i don't want to update java.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    public class testjavafile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            testjavafile.call_me();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
         public static void call_me() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("https://httpbin.org/post");
            Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("name", "Jinu Jawad");
            params.put("email", "helloworld@gmail.com");
            params.put("CODE", 1111);
            params.put("message", "Hello Post Test success");
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry param : params.entrySet()) {
               if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                   try {
                       postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey().toString(), "UTF-8"));
                       postData.append('=');
                       postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
            }
            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            // this place is showing error

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
                sb.append((char)c);
            String response = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
            JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");
            System.out.println("origin- "+myResponse.getString("origin"));
            System.out.println("url- "+myResponse.getString("url"));
            JSONObject form_data = myResponse.getJSONObject("form");
            System.out.println("CODE- "+form_data.getString("CODE"));
            System.out.println("email- "+form_data.getString("email"));
            System.out.println("message- "+form_data.getString("message"));
            System.out.println("name"+form_data.getString("name"));
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post stack traces as screen-shot. Eclipse allows to copy them to clipboard and the paste it into your question has code/pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop and pc have the same network environment?
It seems your pc can't connect to the network

Comment: my lap is having the household internet. But pc is workmachine ,im connecting f5 vpn in that.but anyhow i can browse in pc too.internet connection is fine in pc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to establish a HTTPS connection to httpbin.org. HTTPS and the security layer SSL/TLS it uses exists in different versions: SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.2, TLS 1.2, TLS 1.3.

Because of security problems most web servers have disabled all versions below TLS 1.2.
But you are lucky, at the moment httpbin.org supports even the older TLS 1.0 and TLS1.1 version.

Your problem is that your used Java version 1.5 is very old and no longer supported. So old that as far as I know it does not even support the deprecated version TLS 1.0.

Therefore you need at least Java 1.6 which supports TLS 1.0: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider

But my recommendation would be to upgrade to Java 7 or better 8 as in Java 8 TLS 1.2 is supported and enabled by default.

Comment: @ArvindSmylz On Stackoverflow you can say "thank you" by upvoting and accepting the most helpful answer. See the up button left to my answer and the gray/green checkmark.